# How can I query an individual lambda metric in kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I am using metricbeat to query metrics and save them in elasticsearch from AWS and using Kibana to search the metric. I am able to see lambda metrics based on this doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-aws-lambda.html

It shows me the summary of top usage lambdas in the view but how can I query an individual lambda metrics? Ideally I'd like to query lambda by its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the sample response in the documentation you linked, it seems that the lambda name is stored in the `aws.dimensions.FunctionName` field. Then, if you're using the Kibana Query Language, your can filter your data with something like `aws.dimensions.FunctionName: your-lambda-name`

Comment: yes I know there is a field but how can I search them in Metrics view?